# Multi device management in GitLab CI/CD pipelines

Tags: testing, gitlab, embedded, cicd

There are several Embedded Linux devices connected over Ethernet. The goal is to install a software image which was generated by a previous pipeline on one of the available devices. After successfully uploading the image a set of Python tests shall be executed.

For managing the different IP addresses I have used the [one runner, multiple workers](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/fleet_scaling/#intermediate-configuration-one-runner-multiple-workers) concept. For each worker I have defined a variable `DUT_IP` which points to a device. For a single job in the pipeline this works as intended.

```
concurrent = 2
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[[runners]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  name = "Laboratory Tests runner  #2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  url = "https://gitlab-ee.dev.ifm/"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  token = "XXXXX"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  executor = "docker"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  environment = ["DUT_IP=192.168.0.70"]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [[runners]]
  name = "Laboratory Tests runner #1"
  url = "https://gitlab-ee.dev.ifm/"
  token = "XXXXXX"
  executor = "docker"
  environment = ["DUT_IP=192.168.0.71"]
```

By using [Resource groups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/) it can be prevented that multiple jobs are executed on the same device. From my understanding this will not ensure that jobs are executed in a specific order. What I need to ensure is that for each pipeline the following steps are performed:

- Firmware update
- Python Tests
- Test result upload

Of course I could put everything in a single Job which will become quite big. Are there other more general solutions. Maybe with dynamic environments. Unfortunately I was not able to find any good blueprint on this kind of set-up online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution to the device management is by using labgrid with tags. See my answer in the labgrid discussion https://github.com/labgrid-project/labgrid/discussions/1244#discussioncomment-6509711